# Bad performance ListView in TabControl WPF

Tags: wpf, performance, listview, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with three `TabItems`. Each `TabItem` has its own ViewModel. The last tab contains a `ListView` with +1500 records. So every time I open this tab, it takes +-10 seconds to render. I want to optimize the `ListView` so it doesn't take that long to render every time.

I'm binding a `ObservableCollection` to the `ListView`.

The `ListView` looks like this

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader>
                   <TextBox... custom templates for filtering here
                </GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
    <ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I've already tried:

```
<VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
```

This speeds it up, but makes scrolling reeeeeeeally slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can separate your big collection on the few small pages (20/50 items) and add new items by a little. I can recommend you to use Behavior for refresh the page. Just bind awaitable command to add new items to the collection.
New items will be adding while scrollig down.

```
internal class ScrollEndToCommandBehavior : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
{
    #region Public Static Fields and Constants

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof (object), typeof (ScrollEndToCommandBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof (ICommand), typeof (ScrollEndToCommandBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }


    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Protected Methods

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.ViewChanged += AssociatedObjectOnViewChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.ViewChanged -= AssociatedObjectOnViewChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void AssociatedObjectOnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!eventArgs.IsIntermediate && Math.Abs(AssociatedObject.ScrollableHeight - AssociatedObject.VerticalOffset) < 5)
        {
            Command?.Execute(CommandParameter);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! After some modifications, that worked like a charm. Worth mentioning that `ViewChanged` is only for UWP. If someone wants to use this with WPF, use `ScrollChanged`. I've also changed the behavior so it can be be attached to the `ListView` itself and in the `OnAttaching` I extract the `ScrollViewer` from the `ListView`. Thanks again :)